# Why does using try in conjuntion with affjax's XHRError result in a mismatch on the Error type?

Tags: purescript

I'd like to be able to catch communications errors when using affjax in purescript. I try it like this:

```
module Main where

import Prelude

import Affjax as AX
import Affjax.ResponseFormat as ResponseFormat
import Data.Argonaut.Core (stringify, fromString)
import Data.Either (Either(..))
import Data.HTTP.Method (Method(..))
import Effect.Aff (launchAff)
import Effect.Class.Console (log)

import Effect.Exception(message)
import Control.Monad.Error.Class (try)


main = void $ launchAff $ do
  resultEi <- try $ AX.get ResponseFormat.string "/api"
  let result = case resultEi of
        Left err -> Left $ AX.XHRError err
        rightRes@(Right _)-> rightRes
  case result of
    Left err -> log $ "GET /api response failed to decode: " <> AX.printError err
    Right response -> log $ "GET /api response: " <> response.body
```

This results in the somewhat confusing error, particularly so because I'm not really sure what would be here other than `Effect.Exception.Error` since both `Aff` and `XHRError` seem to use this `Error` datatype.

```
Error 1 of 1

  Could not match type

    Error

  with type

    Error


while trying to match type Either Error
  with type Either Error
while checking that expression rightRes
  has type t0
in value declaration main

where t0 is an unknown type
```

Answer (score 2):

The branches of your `case` have different types.

The `Left` branch has type `Either Effect.Exception.Error a`, because that's how you construct it.

But your `Right` branch has the same type as `rightRes`, because that's what you're returning from it, and that type is `Either Affjax.Error (Response _)`.

So the types don't match.

To make them match, you have to unwrap `rightRes` and rewrap it again:

```
let result = case resultEi of
      Left err -> Left $ AX.XHRError err
      Right res -> Right res
```

Yes, it will have the exact same content, but the type will be different.

---

But if your intent is just to change the type of the error, then I'd recommend [`lmap` from `Bifunctor`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-bifunctors/4.0.0/docs/Data.Bifunctor#v:lmap):

```
let result = lmap AX.XHRError resultEi
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer made me wonder why I'd need to unwrap both Left and Right, as the Left's type `Either Effect.Exception.Error a` should have `a` inferred as `(Response _)`. When I tried your suggestion, there was another type error, which made me realize what I really needed was just: `Right res -> res`, thus absolving the outer `Either`. This would change the handy suggestion to use `lmap` to be: `join $ lmap AX.XHRError resultEi`.